# Having trouble in writing basic pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

Write a pseudocode that will compute and print the products of `N` integers.

**Hint**: `N` is the limit of your loop. For example,

```
while y <= N: product = product * y
```

I don't get the problem so I can't think of anything, I am new to this.

Comment: The problem here is the poorly worded problem statement; whoever formulated this task did a bad job.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
PRINT("N = __")    // Asks the user to input what "n" is
n <-- INT(USERINPUT) // The answer must be an integer (non-decimal). It saves this to the variable "n".

y <-- [] // Makes a blank array called "y"

FOR n: // Allows the below code to run as a maximum, "n" times. It's a loop, so repeats.
    PRINT("Add the number: ") // Asks the user to input an integer
    input <-- (USERINPUT)     // For the first iteration (loop), it saves the answer to "y", but for the other loops, it replaces the previous value
    IF input == "break" THEN: // If the user answered "break" - it is case-sensitive.
 ​       print (y) // Prints our array with our integers
        break // Ends the code
    ELSE: // If the user did not answer "break".
        y.append(input) // Appends (adds) our answer to the array "y"
```